# Laravel SIde Menu Id not Working Here

Tags: php, html, laravel

I will Try to Click Category On my Side Post But Not Working Here........
And I will Provide Html Code On Laravel Project Please CHeck it........
WHy Laravel Not showing input ID on Menu bar....

```html
<div class="templatemo_right_section">
    <div class="tag_section">
        <ul id="countrytabs" class="shadetabs">
            <li><a href="#" rel="search" class="selected">Search</a></li>                
            <li><a href="#"  id="category" rel="category">Category</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="archive">Archive</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div class="tabcontent_section">
        <div id="search" class="tabcontent">
            <form method="get" action="#">
                <input class="inputfield" name="searchkeyword" type="text" id="searchkeyword"/>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Search" />
            </form>                    
        </div>
     
        <div id="category" class="tabcontent">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Duis mollis</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Maecenas adipiscing</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Nunc blandit orci</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cum sociis natoque</a></li>
            </ul>                        
        </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOXQX.png)

Comment: Maybe your issue on tab content display. You need to use  `href="#category"` instead of `id="category"` in your tab menu.

Comment: Not WorkIng................Kemon Asen Nasir Bai